# How do units work when integrating a distribution that has units?

Tags: integration, dimensional-analysis, units, absorption

In case some want more context, the source which I'm using (could be wrong...?) is:
https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0202029 (Eqs. 2,5,7)

The equations of concern are:

$$\sigma_a(\omega) = \sigma_0 g(\omega)$$
$$[\sigma_a(\omega)] = length^2$$

$$\sigma_0 = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \sigma(\omega) d\omega$$
$$[\sigma_0] = length^2 time^{-1}$$

where the line shape is normalized,
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(\omega) d\omega = 1$$
$$[g(\omega)] = frequency^{-1} = time$$

From what I understand, absorption cross sections have the units of $length^2$ and $\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(\omega) d\omega = 1$ should be unitless because $[d\omega] = frequency$ and $[g(\omega)] = frequency^{-1}$.

Therefore the units of this equation are incorrect...?
$$\sigma_0 = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \sigma(\omega) d\omega = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \sigma_0 g(\omega) d\omega$$
**$$length^2 \times time^{-1} \neq length^2 \times frequency^{-1} \times frequency$$**

Do I have some mistake in my reasoning or is there a mistake in the source I'm using?

Comment: Are you suggesting there is a problem? I don't see any! Based on my experience you're working with photoabsorption and related quantities such as the photoabsorption cross section and the optical oscillator strength of a transition. By the way, you can find the published version of the paper here: https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1119/1.12937?casa_token=PMHkv4tsknoAAAAA:nUZo2QYrMJOUvHBANhQyLvzub8r-dk3dquBpLyjMw24Ldam-q8eBmapbZgdWMZX_KXta8a8TgMw

Comment: The right hand side of your equation actually reads $\text{Length}^2\times \text{frequency} \times \text{frequency}^{-1} \times \text{frequency}$

Comment: Are $\sigma(\omega)$ and $\sigma_a(\omega)$ meant to be the same thing? If not, what is the difference between the two, and how are they related?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct units of the parameters in your question are as follows:
$\sigma(\omega)$ is the photoabsorption cross section in units of m$^2$ or cm$^2$, $g(\omega)$ is the lineshape function in units of Hz$^{-1}$, $d\omega$ is a differential element of frequency in units of Hz, and $\sigma_{0}$ is the photoabsorption cross section integrated over frequency as you put in the question. This quantity is related to the optical oscillator strength of the transition as discussed in equation (10) of [Morton, D. C., & Noreau, L. (1994). A compilation of electronic transitions in the CO molecule and the interpretation of some puzzling interstellar absorption features. The astrophysical journal supplement series, 95, 301-343](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/pdf/1994ApJS...95..301M). You can find the same expression in the paper you mentioned as well.

Comment: Apologies, I misread that.

Comment: Intuitively, I would have thought that $[\sigma_0] = [\sigma(\omega)]$ since $g(\omega)$ captures the lineshape. Maybe I'm just confused from the definition. Is there a reason for not defining $\sigma_0$ as $\int \sigma(\omega) g(\omega) d\omega $? Why is it $\sigma_0 = \int \sigma(\omega) d\omega$ without $g(\omega)$?

Comment: I think since both $\sigma_{0}$ and $\sigma(\omega)$ have the same symbol, automatically we think that they may have the same unit. I think its fundamental to understand that the Einstein transition probability $A$ is related to the optical oscillator strength which is related to $\sigma_{0}$. That may be the justification for $\sigma_{0}$. $\sigma(\omega)$ and the lineshape function basically help describe the dispersion of the transition due to processes such as doppler broadening, predissociation, radiation trapping, etc.